# How is generic type 'T constrained on this Don Syme's code?

Tags: generics, f#, constraints

```
let compareOn f x (yobj: obj) =
     match yobj with
     | :? 'T as y -> compare (f x) (f y)
     | _ -> invalidArg "yobj" "cannot compare values of different types"
```

I don't see how **'T** above relates to the type of x.
Why is not the type of x just **'a** ?

Used in:

```
type stamp = int

[<CustomEquality; CustomComparison>]
type MyUnionType =
    | MyUnionType of stamp * (int -> int) 

    static member Stamp (MyUnionType (s,_)) = s

    override x.Equals y = equalsOn MyUnionType.Stamp x y
    override x.GetHashCode() = hashOn MyUnionType.Stamp x
    interface System.IComparable with
      member x.CompareTo y = compareOn MyUnionType.Stamp x y
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why has to do with the uses of `x`.  The value `x` and `y` are used as arguments to the same call back: `f x` and `f y`.  The type of `y` in this expression is known to be `T` hence `x` must also be of a type compatible with `T` so F# chooses `T`

Comment: magic. may be a tad too much for me. here is a case where I would write the types down. thank you for the explanation